# How is an object returned from a function?

Tags: php, object

I don't understand how it's possible to return an object from a function. Since objects are passed and returned by reference, If I created an object in a function, I'd expect such object to be destroyed after the function finishes executing. So such returned object reference should be referring to non-existing(destroyed) object. But my object created within a function is successfully returned. How come??

```
class O{
    public $ppty = "ppty value";
}

function f1(){
    $o1 = new O();
    return $o1;
}

var_dump(f1());


**Result:**
object(O)[15]
  public 'ppty' => string 'ppty value' (length=10)
```

Comment: Object lifetime is not connected to variable lifetime.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is there any document you could refer me to about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable "holding" an object is actually holding a reference to the object. The object exists somewhere in memory, the variable referring to the object just holds the memory address (oversimplified). *That's* the reference. When returning that reference or passing it somewhere or assigning it to another variable, *a copy of that reference is made* (meaning the memory address value is copied; e.g. you return the value `0xDEADBEAF` from your function; again, oversimplified). Those references are counted as a property of the object; only when the reference count reaches 0 (no variable is holding a reference to the object anymore), is the object garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following example:

```
$var = 'test';
$ref = &$var;
unset($ref);
echo $var; // Echoes "test".
```

The unset is only removing the reference of `$var` to `$ref`, not destroying the original variable that `$ref` refers to. This is similar to your example of objects being references, and the garbage collection only removes the variable's reference to the object, but the object still exists in memory.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php for more details.

Answer (score 1):

When a function or scope of application is finished the local variables that are no longer accessible will be deleted. However, when you create object from a class the scenario is different. They won't be deleted automatically, there is a garbage collector in php that is constantly searching for objects that are no longer accessible and if it finds any it will delete them.

So when you return object reference from function it won't be deleted. If you won't store the reference in any variable GC will delete it later.

For more information about Garbage collector in php please read this link:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php

Answer (score 0):

In PHP all values are stored in zvals. Those zvals contain the actual data and type information. checkout out the following example.

```
<?php 

class O{
    public $ppty = "ppty value";
}

$a = new 0; // $a is pointing to zval(class 0) with refcount 1
$b = $a;    // $a and $b are pointing to zval(class 0) with refcount 2 
$c = $b;    // $a, $b and $c are pointing to zval(class 0) with refcount 3

unset($a)   // new $b and $c are pointing to zval(class 0) with refcount 2

// until the refcount is greater then the 0 the destructor will not called
?>
```

now take a look at the following example

```
<?php

$a = new 0; // $a is pointing to zval(class 0) with refcount 1

unset($a)   // here refcount is 0 and destruct will be called

?>
```

Now come to your example

```
<?php

function f1(){
    $o1 = new O(); // refcount = 1
    return $o1;
}

// now you are returning the object in function f1 and so,
// $o1 is gone after the function scope but the func f1 is now pointing the its reference.


var_dump(f1())


**Result:**
object(O)[15]
  public 'ppty' => string 'ppty value' (length=10)
```

// once the process is finished then it will call the destruct.